# document.location.href not working consistently

Tags: javascript, angularjs, location-href

I have an Angular based site that I'm building and I've hit an odd error that I'm totally stumped on. It's for a law firm. One of the pull down menus is  the list of lawyers. When I click on one, his page loads up fine. If I go to then click on a different lawyer, the url changes to the proper url but two strange things happen.

1) It doesn't actually go there.
2) The entire pulldown shades as if it's mid-click and seems stuck there.

Rather than butcher up code here, I figured I'd just link to the site so you can see it in action. I will, however, copy to here the associated controller since I'm not sure you'll be able to see that easily enough otherwise.

Again, everything works perfectly except when I try to click on an attorney's name when I'm already on the bio page of another attorney.

AttorneyController.js

```
app.controller('AttorneyController', ['$scope', '$location', 'attorneys', '$sce', function($scope, $location, attorneys, $sce) {

var quotelist = [];

$scope.myFunctions = {};

var practiceareas = {
    altdispute: "Alternative Dispute Resolution",
    businesscorp: "Businesses & Corporations",
    estateplanning: "Estate Planning",
    futures: "Futures & Derivatives",
    litigation: "Litigation",
    productliability: "Product Liability",
    realestate: "Real Estate",
    securities: "Securities"
};

// Load bio content 
$scope.myFunctions.load_bio = function(bioNum){
    var urlstr = $basehref + "bio.php#/?bio_id=" + bioNum;
    document.location.href = urlstr;
}

attorneys.success(function(data){
    var quotelist = [];

    function quoteflip(quotelist, id, total){

        window.clearTimeout(timeoutQuotes); 

        var src1 = quotelist[id];

        $("#bio_quotes").fadeOut(500, function(){
            $("#bio_quotes").html(src1).fadeIn(500);
        });

        var idno = (id + 1) % total;

        var timeoutQuotes =  window.setTimeout(function(){quoteflip(quotelist, idno, quotelist.length);}, 5000);
    }

    if($location.search().bio_id > 0){
        $scope.myFunctions.bio_id = $location.search().bio_id;
        var matches = $.grep(data.attorneys, function(obj) { return obj.id == $location.search().bio_id; });

        if (matches.length === 1) {
            $scope.thisAttorney = matches[0];
            quotelist = $scope.thisAttorney.quotes;
            $("#bio_quotes").html(quotelist[0]);
        }

    }else{
        $scope.myFunctions.bio_id = 0;
    };

    $scope.attorneys = data.attorneys;
    $scope.practiceareas = practiceareas;

    var timeoutQuotes =  window.setTimeout(function(){quoteflip(quotelist, 1, quotelist.length);}, 5000);

});


}]);
```

The URL to see this in action is

http://www.gelerinter.com/dev_sites/lksu

click on ATTORNEYS in the top nav and select the first one. Then, once on his page, click ATTORNEYS again and select Mitchell Goldberg.
You'll see the URL change, but everything lock up.

Comment: why are you reloading pages and not using an angular router? Also DOM manipulation should never be done in controller

Comment: No particular reason. I'm not as seasoned in Angular, so it's not my first thought to use a router, I guess. I'm also not as sure how to use a router with parameters. I mean I can figure out how to send it to bio.php. but I'm not sure how to send it there with an id of 1, for example.

Comment: Well if you are using single server page loads, why use angular at all? Look into router tutorials

Comment: because I want to be able to have things like this bio page where I have all the data in a JSON file which I then pull in and only display the correct person, etc. Like I said, I may not be using Angular to its full power, but I'm still relatively new and learning more about it. If you have suggestions, I'm open to hearing them.

Comment: go through the tutorial on angular documentation site...see how they load different product details using route parameters

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But in the meantime, is there a particular reason that this wouldn't be working?

Comment: where does `$baseHref` get defined?

Comment: there's a basehref.html file that gets included at the top. The whole purpose of that is that, sadly, my dev environment doesn't always exactly mirror the directory structure of the prod environment, so I need a way to compensate for that.

Comment: BTW, switched to using a router but now I have a new set of problems. Please feel free to make suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245817/angularjs-routeprovider-not-pulling-in-conten

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to set document.location.href manually, instead use a route provider or location service.

Comment: That's what I'm trying now, but now the routing isn't even working at a basic level. I might end up posting a separate question about that! *sigh*