# AngularJS routeProvider not pulling in content

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm very confused as to why my routing code isn't working. I asked a separate question a bit ago and was told that I should be using routing instead of the method that I was using. So I moved over to routing, which I've done successfully in the past, but it's just not working and I'm lost as to where my issue is.

My actual index.php is simply including the top stuff, then a `<div ng-view></div>` and then the bottom stuff.

This is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module("LKSU", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) { 
$routeProvider
    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'content.php',
        controller  : 'HomeController'
    })

    .when('/bios/:user_id?', {   
        controller: 'AttorneyController', 
        templateUrl: 'bio.php'
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/'
    });

}]);
```

I'm not even up to the `/bio` part working yet since even the plain old `/` isn't working. I go to the root and I see the header, footer, etc, but blankness where the content should be. The only error that shows up in the console is some amazingly long gibberish that seems to be saying something about an injector, which I don't understand.

Here's the Generated HTML code:

```
<html ng-app="LKSU">
<head>
<base href="/">
<script>
$basehref = "/";
</script>
<title>Lawrence, Kamin, Saunders & Uhlenhop LLC</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<!-- Modules -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Services -->
<script src="js/services/attorneys.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="js/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/AttorneyController.js"></script>


</head>

<body ng-controller="HomeController">

<div id="header" class="container-fluid">
<div id="logo">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.gif" border=0 /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 tagline">
            <p>Not just answers.<br/>Solutions.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="navbutton" id="about_button">about us</li>
            <li class="dropdown navbutton" id="attorneys_button" ng-controller="AttorneyController">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">attorneys<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#/bios/2" class="biolink">Thomas F. Bennington, Jr. </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="biolink">Peter E. Cooper </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="biolink">Timothy J. Edmier </a></li>
                        <li><a href="" ng-click="myFunctions.load_bio(1);" class="biolink">Mitchell B. Goldberg </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shannon L. Hartzler </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ted A. Koester </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Kent Lawrence </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Robert J. Lawrence </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">John F. Mahoney </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Christina M. Mermigas </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">John S. Monical </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">David L. Reich </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Charles J. Risch </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Raymond E. Saunders </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Robert L. Schlossberg </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Paul B. Uhlenhop </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Michael Wise </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Joseph A. Zarlengo </a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
            <li class="navbutton" id="areas_button">practice areas</li>
            <li class="navbutton" id="studies_button">case studies</li>
            <li class="navbutton" id="news_button">news & events</li>
            <li class="navbutton" id="articles_button">articles & presentations</li>
            <li class="navbutton" id="contact_button">contact us</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>



<br clear="all" />
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">

<div ng-view></div>

<br clear="all" />
</div>  

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="footer">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
            <a href="attorneys.html">Attorneys</a>
            <a href="practiceareas.html">Practice Areas</a>
            <a href="clients.html">Clients</a>
            <a href="casestudies.html">Case Studies&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="newsevents.html">News &amp; Events</a>
            <a href="articlespresentations.html">Articles &amp; Presentations</a>
            <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
            <a href="disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a>

            <br/><br/>
            &copy; 2015 Lawrence, Kamin, Saunders &amp; Uhlenhop, LLC
            <br/><br/>
            300 South Wacker Drive, Suite 500, Chicago, Illinois 60606 &nbsp;|&nbsp; P: (312) 372-1947 &nbsp;|&nbsp; F: (312) 372-2389
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the absolute paths of `content.php` and `app.js`? Is developer console showing any errors, 404s or warnings?

Comment: from the site root? /content.php and /js/app.js  The console is showing some sort of very long gibberish message that seems to be saying something about an injection error, but I can't make it out.

Comment: Both url and the site root.

Comment: right now this is off my localhost so lksu.localhost.com/content.php and lksu.localhost.com/js/app.js

Comment: I would say that it's trying to find `content.php` relatively to `app.js` so at `js/content.php`. Try using `/content.php`.

Comment: tried that. nada. :(

Comment: The injection error (and all other stuff in the console) may be important. Can you share it with us?

Comment: See my answer. I feel very sheepish.

Comment: A screenshot will help :-)

Comment: I figured it out. I wasn't including Angular's routing JS file! It had no idea what I was trying to do!

Comment: Haha :-) Console should warn about missing $routeProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and I'm just guessing.

```
    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
// router for the home page
.when('/', {
templateUrl: 'content.php'
controller: 'HomeController'
})

.when('/bios/:user_id?', {
controller: 'AttorneyController',
templateUrl: 'bio.php'
})

.otherwise({
redirectTo:'/'
});
});
```

Comment: Tried that too. (and just did again, to be sure) - nada. Is something possibly wrong on the HTML side?

Answer (score 0):

DOH!!!!

I forgot to include angular's routing file:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>`